# The magento 2 checkout page fills in the shipping adress function disappears, how to set it up to show it?

Tags: checkout, shipping

The magento 2 checkout page fills in the shipping adress function disappears, how to set it up to show it?
The user is unable to fill in the shipping address!
This is my site, you can try it! [supwatch.com](http://supwatch.com)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a different reason to shipping address function not appear.

**Please go through the below check list and confirm.**

1. If you have added a Virtual Product to your shopping cart. In this case Shipping section of checkout is not shown. Please try with the different product, which has weight, and let us know if it worked.
2. It might be chance if you not added weight to your product so you can export products to csv update weight and import file back to magento
   System->Data Transfer-Export.

**For more reference** [click here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3902)